# Loading JSON works with XMLHttpRequest but not with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to get the content of a JSON file from my google storage. I can make it work with XMLHttpRequest, but not with jquery, and I don't know why.

This works:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", fileUrl, true);
xhttp.send();
```

But this doesn't:

```
$.getJSON(fileUrl, function(data) {
  console.log( "success", data);
});
```

The file is stored in my google storage https://storage.googleapis.com/
I have set the cors to allow any origin (using wildcard *) using gsutil.

Only with jquery I get

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/...' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How do I make this work with jquery? As I find the XMLHttpRequest solution very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `fetch()`? I know it's not jQuery, but it looks much nicer than an `XMLHttpRequest`:

```js
// with async-await:
(async function() {
  const response1 = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  const json1 = await response1.json()
  console.log('Async-await:', json1)
})();

// with Promise:
const response2 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json2 => console.log('Promise:', json2));
```